# This update is for an app downloaded with a different Apple ID. Sign in with that Apple ID and try again

Tags: macos

After upgrading to Yosemite I see under App Store > Updates.

> This update is for an app downloaded with a different Apple ID. Sign
>   in with that Apple ID and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works for me is this hint from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5532426?start=45&tstart=0

> I solved this problem, instead of going to the update page go to the
>   app itself within the App store.  Here it will say "Accept" where it
>   usually says download and then it will reauthorize you